# Jenkinsfile - how to access other github files?

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm performing an api call in my jenkinsfile that requires specifying a path to file 'A'. Assuming file A is located on the same repo, I am not sure how to refer to file A when running the jenkinsfile.

I feel like this has been done before, but I can't find any resource. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don‘t quite understand what you are trying to achieve. The api call path is determined from a *file* in the repository? Could you give a few more details?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether you are using a scripted or declaritive Jenkinsfile, as the details differ. However the principle is the same as far as I am concerned. Basically to do anything with a file you will need to be within a node clause - essentially the controller opens a session on one of the agents and does actions there. You need to checkout your repo on that node:

The scripted Jenkinsfile would look something like (assuming you are not bothered about which node you are running on):

```
node("") {
    checkout scm // "scm" equates to the configuration that the job was run with
    // the whole repo will be now available
}
```